# Why get Integer[] cannot be converted to int

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Solution {
    public int removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {        
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            if(!al.contains(i)){
                al.add(i);
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i<al.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(al.get(i));
        }
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[al.size()];
        arr = al.toArray(arr);
        
        return   arr;    
    }
}
```

I can not understanding What's wrong with my code. Below is my error:

> Line 16: error: incompatible types: Integer[] cannot be converted to int
> return   arr;

Comment: The error should be self explanatory... Can't return an array from a function that's defined as returning an int.

Comment: You have to up vote the answer if it is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Integer[]` class using the `int[]` to create an array and change the code accordingly or else change the **return type of function** from `int[]` to `Integer[]`.

Your can change like this,

```
static int[] your_Func_Name() {
   //Your code
}
```

Or Else,

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i< nums.length;i++){
            if(!al.contains(i)){
                al.add(i);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<al.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(al.get(i));
        }

        //Initializing the array using int[] and not Integer[]

        int[] arr = new int[al.size()];

        //ArrayList al elements are manually copied to array

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = al.get(i);
        }

        return arr;
```